# drupal_add_js does not add javascript on after_build

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I'm using the following line to add JavaScript code to my module form:

```
$form['#after_build'][] = 'myModule_after_build'
```

In `myModule_after_build()`, I add the Javascript code with calling `drupal_add_js('myJavascript','inline')`.

Unfortunately, it seems that the JavaScript code is added only during the first page call.
I would like to pass some arguments to JavaScript, and manipulate the content of the JavaScript, according to the options in the form.

Is there any configuration that I can set to add 'myJavascript' with different arguments to every button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#after_build` is called every time the form it built. I've used this myself many times to add JS to forms. Most likely you have a flaw in the script or after build function itself, or you are using cached data when creating the script to display.

If you posted your code, we could provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I'm using drupal_add_js to add a highcharts javascript. I'm calling this script as it is. I hope there is no flaws in it. When i've manually clear the caches using the admin menu (flush cache tables), the javascript was added.

Comment: @danielmsd I need to see your actual code, not a description of it